# Prove that $A \circ B = AB$ if and only if both $A$ and $B$ are diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, hadamard-product

**Definition. Hadamard product.** Let $A,B \in \mathbb{C}^{m \times n}$. The Hadamard product of $A$ and $B$ is defined by $[A \circ B]_{ij} = [A]_{ij}[B]_{ij}$ for all $i = 1, \dots, m$, $j = 1, \dots, n$.

**Remark.** See details in this [Hadamard product wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_%28matrices%29).

There is the following remark in [Million's paper](http://buzzard.ups.edu/courses/2007spring/projects/million-paper.pdf) in Chapter 2:

> We can relate the Hadamard product with matrix multiplication via
>   considering diagonal matrices, since $A \circ  B = AB$ if and only if
>   both $A$ and $B$ are diagonal.

So there is a theorem, that *$A \circ  B = AB$ if and only if both $A$ and $B$ are diagonal*, but I don't know how to *prove* it, and I didn't find it in the literature, because not many books have written in this topic.

**Edit.** In this theorem probably $m=n$. Million didn't write about it.

Comment: If you mean by $AB$ the standard product , isn't $m=n$?

Comment: Yes, you are right, in this theorem $m = n$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The theorem you are trying to prove is not true:

Consider $A = B = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0\\
1 & 0\end{array}\right)$.

Comment: Also the other direction is wrong? This part of @brd's proof seems good for me. What do you think?

Comment: The other direction ($A$, $B$ diagonal $\implies A \circ B = AB$) is right indeed (it would not be an exaggeration to call this implication trivial, though).

Comment: Generalizing this example, any projection all of whose elements are $1$ or $0$ will do the job.

Comment: @Ian and can you say any condition to complete the statment? So I mean a necessary and sufficient condition.

Comment: I would be surprised that there is a nice necessary and sufficient condition to write (other than the ugly system of equations), but I could be wrong.

Comment: Then just see the class of $(A,B)$ pairs of matrices, that satisfies $A \circ B = AB$. As we have seen diagonal matrices are good, and also $A=B=P$ matrices where $P$ is a [projector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_%28linear_algebra%29) with elements from $\{0,1\}$. Anything else?

Comment: Yes, there are lots of other things, and I don't think there is a global description of such pairs. It is not hard to come up with examples for 2x2 matrices, you should try.

Comment: Yes I know that there are others, but I thought that maybe we could describe it somehow.

Answer (score -1):

Proof: (assuming $n=m$)

($\Rightarrow$) by assumption, $A$ and $B$ are diagonal.  Then $AB = diag(a_{11}b_{11}, a_{22}b_{22}, \dots, a_{nn}b_{nn})$ and $[A\circ B]_{i,j} = [A]_{i,j} [B]_{i,j}$.  Since $A$ and $B$ are diagonal, then $[A\circ B]_{i,j} = 0$ for all $i\neq j$, and $[A\circ B]_{i,i} = a_{ii}b_{ii}$ $\Rightarrow$ $[A\circ B]_{i,j} = diag(a_{11}b_{11}, a_{22}b_{22}, \dots, a_{nn}b_{nn})=AB$

($\Leftarrow$) (retracted)

Comment: Thanks a lot, nice proof, I'm really sorry, but I don't understand the end of your post. "This produces a set of $n$ linear equations in $n^4$ unknowns, ..." If $i$ runs from $1$ to $n$ and $j$ also runs from $1$ to $n$, then how could it be $n$ equations? And $n^4$ unknowns? And I did not see from where the solutions come from. Can you write about it a little bit more? Thanks!

Comment: There are $n^2$ equations corresponding to $n^2$ entries of $AB$. Also, the equations are *not* linear (for example: $a_{ij}b_{ij}$).

Comment: I downvoted this answer because it is not a proof ("whose only non-trivial solution is..": Why? Prove it!). Also, what it claims to prove is false (if I'm not mistaken, see my answer).